# How does this linkedin data get into cookies sent to my app?

Tags: http, cookies, web

Looking at some of the cookies sent to my server from someone on a website I created.  How did this get sent to my domain?   My app has NOTHING to do with linkedin whatsoever.

COOKIES:'__utmz': '12835621.1375736347.22.3.utmcsr=linkedin.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/profile/view',

Could this be a browser extension injecting stuff?  If so, to what end?  This cookie came to me, how does it do linkedin any good?

When I search for `utmscr=linkedin.com` there are LOTS of hits from lots of unlikely places....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Short**

This is a cookie set by google analytics on a user's browser. This was sent to your server along-with other cookie data. For the above case, the user visited your website from LinkedIn.com

**In Details**

Google Analytics does tracking by using the tracking cookies. When someone visits a website that is properly coded with Google Analytics Tracking Code, that website sets four first-party cookies on the visitor’s computer automatically. They are __utma, __utmb & __utmc, __utmz, __utmv.

__utmz Stores the traffic source or campaign that explains how the user reached your site. The cookie is created when the javascript library executes and is updated every time data is sent to Google Analytics. It keeps track of where the visitor came from, what search engine you used, what link you clicked on, what keyword you used, and where they were in the world when you accessed a website. It expires in 15,768,000 seconds – or, in 6 months. This cookie is how Google Analytics knows to whom and to what source / medium / keyword to assign the credit for a Goal Conversion or an Ecommerce Transaction. __utmz also lets you edit its length with a simple customization to the Google Analytics Tracking code.

**Refer to**
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage